# Add params to URL on render rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

Is it possible to add params to url while rendering view on controller?
Here I'm trying to add `tab=2` on the url.So that my new url looks like `localhost:3000/organizations/new?tab=2`

I tried the following code

```
render 'organizations/new', tab: 2
```

but it neither change the URL nor add the params on URL it just render the view.

I also tried  `render 'organizations/new?tab=2'` It throws `ActionView::MissingTemplate`.

## EDIT 1

Here is my organization/new.html.erb code

```
    <!-- START PAGE CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container page-navigation-top-fixed" id="organization-new">
  <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
  <%= render 'shared/navigation' %>
  <div class="page-content">
    <%= render 'shared/header' %>
    <!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
    <div class="page-content-wrap">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default tab-panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="tab-container" id="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                  <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">
                      <%= t('admins.create_organization') %>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="disabled">
                    <a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab" class="disabled">
                      <%= t('organization.add_profile') %>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="org tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-1">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <%= render 'organizations/add_edit_org_form' %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-2">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <%= render 'organizations/add_business_profile_tab' %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
  </div>
  <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
</div>
<!-- END PAGE CONTAINER -->
```

here is my 'organizations/add_edit_org_form' partial which is renders on first tab

```
    <%= form_for (@organization), html: {class: 'form-horizontal organization-form', id: 'add_edit_organization'} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:name, t('organization.label_name'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.text_field(:name, class: 'form-control', organization_id: @organization.id) %>
        <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="organization_name_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:abbreviation, t('organization.label_abbr'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.text_field(:abbreviation, class: 'form-control', organization_id: @organization.id) %>
        <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="organization_abbreviation_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:organization_type, t('organization.label_type'), class: 'col-md-3
      col-xs-12 control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.select(:organization_type, options_for_organization_type, {}, class: 'form-control select') %>
        <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="organization_type_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:primary_currency, t('organization.label_primary_currency'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.select(:primary_currency, options_for_primary_currency, {}, class: 'form-control select') %>
        <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="organization_primary_currency_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:status, t('organization.label_status'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.select(:status, options_for_status, {}, class: 'form-control select') %>
        <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="organization_status_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:country_id, t('organization.label_country'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12
      control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 select-country-options">
        <%= f.select(:country_id, options_for_countries, {}, class: 'form-control select') %>
        <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="organization_country_id_error"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label(:payment_method_id, t('organization.label_payment_method'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <%= f.select(:payment_method_id, options_for_payment_methods, {}, class: 'form-control select') %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">

      <button class="btn btn-primary ajax-spinner pull-right">
        <%= t('organization.label_submit') %>
        <span class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-right"></span>
      </button>
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x pull-right"></i>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and here is my another partials 'organizations/add_business_profile_tab' which is renders on second tab

```
<%= form_for (@business_profile), html: {class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'add_business_profile', multipart: true} do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12  control-label"><%= t('business_profile.upload_your_logo') %></label>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="image-frame" id="upload_logo_div">
      <%= image_tag 'upload.jpg', class: 'image-frame', id: 'logo_image' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.file_field(:logo, id: 'logo_upload_btn') %>
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="logo_upload_btn_error"></span>
    <div id="date_picker_container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.hidden_field(:organization_id, value: @organization.id, id: 'organization_id') %>
  <%= f.label(:email, t('business_profile.email'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <%= f.text_field(:email, class: 'form-control', organization_id: @organization_id) %>
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="business_profile_email_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label(:address, t('business_profile.address'), class: 'col-md-3
  col-xs-12 control-label') %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <%= f.text_field(:address, class: 'form-control') %>
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="business_profile_address_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label(:phone, t('business_profile.phone'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <%= f.text_field(:phone, class: 'form-control') %>
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="business_profile_phone_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label(:contact_person_name, t('business_profile.contact_person_name'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label') %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <%= f.text_field(:contact_person_name, class: 'form-control') %>
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="business_profile_contact_person_name_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group ">
  <%= f.label(:registration_date, t('business_profile.registration_date'), class: 'col-md-3 col-xs-12
  control-label') %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <%= f.text_field(:registration_date, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: 'off', value: @business_profile.registration_date.nil? ? '' : @business_profile.registration_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')) %>
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="business_profile_registration_date_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <%= f.hidden_field(:organization_id) %>
    <input type="hidden" value=<%= Date.today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %> name="today_date" id="today_date">
    <span class="org-error-block text-danger text-danger" id="business_profile_organization_id_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
    <%= t('business_profile.label_submit') %>
    <span class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-right"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

## NOTE

I want to be stay on second tab after the form submission on both success and failure cases.

Comment: Can you post your `organizations/new.html.erb`?

Comment: In `new.html.erb` you are using `form_for`? @bipashant

Comment: @Prashant4020 Yes I'm using form_for

Comment: Then please use like this `<% form_for @organization, path(@organization, :tab => 2) %>`

Comment: Please post your `organizations/new.html.erb`

Comment: @Pavan
I added my view code

Comment: I think passing params is ok, try adding 'active' class to the tab you want

Answer (score 4):

try this one.

```
render 'organizations/new', :locals => {tab:2}
```

Another solution:
On new organizations link pass the tab like

```
link_to 'New Organization', new_organization_path(tab: 2)
```

This will exactly same as you want

```
localhost:3000/organizations/new?tab=2
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't did it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when `render` method is executed in controller, it parses the targeted view template in your case `organizations/new`. It has nothing to do with changing the HTTP request URL and params.

instead you do like this

```
form_for (@organization, url: organization_path(@organization, tab: 2) )
```

This will make the params `tab=2` in the address bar after the completion of the request.

Moreover, it looks like the term `tab=2` is not fixed, it might change at run time so you may use jQuery to modify the `action` attribute of the `form` like

```
$('#target_form').attr('action', old_value + '?tab=2');
```

Comment: Thank you 
You saved me again